# How to edit line length in SolidWorks using API?

Tags: vba, api, solidworks

I'm trying to edit line length in Sketch in SolidWorks.

I saw that working in a tutorial.

I get

> Object variable or With block variable not set

Screenshot from solid
[image]

```vb
Sub main()

    Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
    Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    
    swModel.AddConfiguration3 "test", Empty, Empty, 0
    
    Dim swDim As SldWorks.Dimension
    
    Set swDim = swModel.Parameter("D1.@Szkic1")
    
    swDim.SetSystemValue3 0.005, swThisConfiguration, Empty  '(THIS LINE GETS HIGHLIGHTED)
    
    swModel.ForceRebuild3 True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be : "D1@Szkic1" instead of "D1.@Szkic1"

To be sure, you can add the following line after "Set swDim":

```
If swDim Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Error Selecting Dimension"
```